# AntiForgery with ASPX Webmethods

Tags: jquery, webforms, csrf, client-side, webmethod

I am implementing AntiForgery into a WebApplication. Whilst I know this works server side using the AntiForgery Library by adding a hidden element and then validating it on a master page event, we have hundreds of ASPX Page WebMethods to consider when it comes to client side implementation with jQuery or reactJs.

Is there a way of creating a filter to tag onto WebMethods that does an AntiForgery check?

Comment: Welcome to S/O. This looks pretty good for a first question, though I admittedly don't know these technologies so it may need more detail or focus to get a good answer. I'm going to edit it lightly slightly to conform to the norms of the site.